# Extjs Grid render only first row

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am extjs beginner. 
I have a grid where I need to color each column based on some condition. 
I created the grid and added a renderer to each grid element.

The result works as expected but only for the first row and I need to have the color code applied to all rows.
Any clue about what I am doing wrong ?

I use extjs 4.3

below code and result image.

```
Ext.define('Example.grid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.testGrid',
height: 240,
margin: '10',
store: 'teststore',
requires: [
    'tests.contextmenu'
],
columns: [
    { xtype: 'gridcolumn', width:70,  dataIndex: 'running', text: 'Running',
    renderer: function(value, meta) {
              if (value != 0)
                    meta.tdCls = 'row-background-lightyellow';
              return value;}},
    { xtype: 'gridcolumn', width:70,  dataIndex: 'completed', text: 'Completed', 
    renderer: function(value, meta){
            if (value!=0)
                    meta.tdCls = 'row-background-lightgreen';
            return value;}},
    { xtype: 'gridcolumn', width:70,  dataIndex: 'failed', text: 'Failed', 
    renderer: function(value, meta){
            if (value!=0)
                    meta.tdCls = 'row-background-lightred';
            return value;} },
    { xtype: 'gridcolumn', width:70,  dataIndex: 'waiting', text: 'Waiting', 
    renderer: function(value, meta) {
            if (value!=0)
                    meta.tdCls = 'row-background-lightgrey';
            return value;} },
    { xtype: 'gridcolumn', dataIndex: 'jobid', text: 'Job Id' },
    { xtype: 'gridcolumn', dataIndex: 'jobname', text: 'Name', renderer: rendergrey},
    { xtype: 'gridcolumn', dataIndex: 'reason', text: 'Info', flex: 1 }
],

initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments)
refresh: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.getView().refresh();
}
});
function rendergrey(value, meta) {
       if (value!=0)
            meta.tdCls += 'row-background-lightgrey';
       return value;
   };
```

And here the result:
[image]

Comment: It's been a while since I use Extjs. I think you need to use the viewconfig property and getRowClass function. Define a css class for each column and apply that css in your getRowClass function depending of the value

Comment: Inspect the dom, are the classes being applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a third, fourth and fifth row to your data set, you may see a pattern: the issue is caused by the alternating row's lightgray background color overwriting your custom color.

You did not add your CSS code, but I suspect you may want to add an `!important` behind the color to give it preference over the alt-row's `background-color`. E.g.

```
.row-background-lightyellow {
    background-color: #ffc !important;
}
```

Or you may want to remove the alternating color completely using the [`viewConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-viewConfig) on your `grid`:

```
viewConfig: {
    stripeRows: false
}
```

A third possibility is to use inline CSS, which always has preference over CSS styles:

```
// meta.tdCls = 'row-background-lightyellow'
meta.style = 'background-color: #ffc'
```

Comment: great, it's working. very clear explanation. thank you